# Puppeteer: cannot render pdf with images stored locally

Tags: pdf-generation, puppeteer

I cannot get images stored locally to be rendered in generated pdf with Puppeteer, but external images for which I specify a url work.

In particular, in the sample code below, rendering the page in **test_html1** works, while rendering the **test_html2** does not work.

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const test_html1 = `<html><h3>Hello world!</h3><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/1024px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"></html>`;
  // const test_html2 = `<html><h3>Hello world!</h3><img src="file:///home/cristina/Documents/logo.jpg"></html>`;
  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${test_html}`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
  await page.pdf({ path: `${this.outputPath}/test-puppeteer.pdf`,
      format: 'A4', landscape: !data.isPortrait,
      margin: { top: '0.5cm', right: '1cm', bottom: '0.8cm', left: '1cm' }, printBackground: true });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Result with **test_html1**:

[image]

Result with **test_html2**:

[image]

My questions:

- Does Puppeteer work with absolute img paths?
- If yes, am I specifying the path correctly? Or is there something else I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved on Puppeteer GitHub: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1643

Basically, it doesn't work because, as a security measure against malicious websites, access to local images is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

```
function base64_encode(file) {
var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
}
img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64_encode(imagePath);
```

You can use above function it's render very fast.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still facing the issue in 2023 - "puppeteer is not able to load the images or files from relative path" then here is a solution I have find out.

You can run a **http server** in **pm2** or something like that. And then specify the file base url after creating the page in  puppeteer.

Dependency :

```json
    "dependencies" : {
        "http-server": "^14.1.1"
    }
```

Run a http server : `pm2 start http-server -- ./server -p 9453 -c-1`

specify the path in puppeteer : `await page.goto(http://localhost:9453/images)`

Here is a full code version :

```js
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            protocolTimeout: 120 * 1000,
            executablePath: process.env.PUPEETER_EXECUTABLE_PATH,
            headless: true,
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-web-security', '--js-flags="--max-old-space-size=2048"', '--debug-print']
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto(`${process.env.FILE_SERVER_URL}:${process.env.FILE_SERVER_PORT}/${directMail.id}/`);

        const viewportOption = viewPortOptions[0];

        console.log(`Direct Mail ID : ${directMail.id} | Viewport option `, viewportOption)

        await page.setViewport(
            viewportOption
        );

        await page.setContent(directMail.templateHtmlStringUpperPart + concatenatedUsersTemplateHtml + directMail.templateHtmlStringLowerPart,
            {
                waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
            });
```